# Can Eve/Cerberus Do Validation of the Schema Itself?

Tags: python, eve

I would like to do a sort of "pre-validation" of a schema to enforce certain fields are included in a schema used in an Eve resource. I see that we can validate and extend validation using Cerberus (http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/latest/customize.html). I don't want to validate the data against the schema, but that the schema contains certain fields itself.

My application is created by allowing other teams in my organization to provide their own resources, and I have a few fields that I would like to enforce that they provide in their schemas.

Is this possible with Eve/Cerberus? I assume that it probably is not and I will have to roll my own. If it isn't available, when is the proper time to inject this validation of the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question. You can make sure a field is included by setting the `required` constraint on it. You can also set a `default` value for a missing field if that can be of any help. See [Schema Definition](http://python-eve.org/config#schema-definition) in the documentation for details.

Comment: I ended up creating a schema and validating the resources provided to my application. Sort of using cerberus to validate cerberus-style schemas. It worked out great.