# Is there a way to get the Cerberus Schema through the API?

Tags: python, cerberus

I am trying to implement an API for other users that is based around YAML files and am using Cerberus to validate the contents of those files. I want to allow the user to specify their own Cerberus schema within those YAML files and validate them as well.

I would like to validate my YAML files using a Cerberus schema like this:

```yaml
description:
  type: string
  required: true
  empty: false
created_on:
  type: datetime
  required: true
created_by:
  type: string
  required: true
  empty: false
properties_schema:
  type: dict
  required: true
  schema: <cerberus_schema>
```

The simplest "solution" is to not validate the contents of the "properties_schema" at all:

```yaml
...
properties_schema:
  type: dict
  required: true
```

This doesn't actually solve the problem though.

I've found an [example of the schema in the documentation](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/api.html#schema-validation-schema) and how the [InspectorValidator generates that schema from the docstrings of the methods](https://github.com/pyeve/cerberus/blob/1.3.x/cerberus/validator.py#L1653-L1670). I haven't been able to find a good way to get that schema information from the Validator though. With the example schema, I could copy the documented schema into my Cerberus schema above and use that but I am worried about maintaining that between Cerberus versions.

I've also found two different stackoverflow questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34401617) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52598161/22437944)) requesting a similar feature that don't really solve my problem unfortunately.

My ideal solution would be to have the Cerberus schema in the schema_registry and reference it within the schema I provide but I know that isn't in place by default. Is there a programmatic solution to get the Cerberus schema instead of just copying it from the documentation into my schema?